# Can't migrate project to Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have a project that I already run in Android Studio.

After I've opened the project in Android Studio I got the message:

**Migrate Project to Gradle?
This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system.
More Information about migrating to Gradle
Don't show this message again.**

Following the link of [More Information about migrating to Gradle](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/intellij_to_gradle) although I'm already on `Android Studio` I've followed the option [Migrating from IntelliJ Projects](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-intellij-projects) .

Since I've already have a `build.gradle` file at the root of my project I've modified to include some dependencies.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

As instructed, i've ran `gradle assembleDebug` on the `Android Studio` terminal windows but was getting some errors. To solve this errors I had to create a `local.properties` with `sdk.dir=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk` and remove the `android-support-v4.jar` file from the `/libs` folder and from the `Libraries->libs` from the `Project Structure`.

I now ran again `gradle assembleDebug` and this time it finishes without any errors.

I've restarted `Android Studio` but after restarting I've saw that on the `External Libraries` of the project there were no `support-v4` and `appcompat-v7` and in one of my classes I have the `import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;` marked as error since `Cannot resolve symbol Cursor Adapter`.

If I press the button `Sync project with gradle files`i got the message: `The project MyProject is not a Gradle-based project`

Can someone help me figuring out how to solve this?

Here is my project Structure

[image]

Comment: try `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` and check if you are getting the same error. Please include you project structure in question for better understanding the problem.

Comment: Added the structure but `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` did not do anything

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The project thinks it's still a non-Gradle based project; it's not the presence of the **build.gradle** file that makes it Gradle-based, but it's how the project was set up in the first place. You'll need to re-import your project to finish the conversion to Gradle.

First, though, it looks like you don't have a **settings.gradle** file; it looks like you need one. Since you've set up your project as a single-module project, then you can put the file in your project's root directory, next to **build.gradle**. It should contain this:

```
import ':'
```

In the future if you add more modules to your project you may want to convert it to a multi-module directory structure, but you don't need to worry about that now. In any event, now you need to do the re-import in Android Studio:

1. Close your project
2. Back up your project
3. Delete the **.idea** folder in the root directory of the project
4. Delete all the **.iml** files in your project
5. Import your project in Android Studio, and in the dialog that prompts you for a file, choose the **build.gradle** file.

After this you should be good to go.

Comment: Yep.You were right. I've re-imported and now everything is OK. Many thanks

Comment: In my case, closing project and re-importing it as "Import non-android studio project" worked. And it created build.gradle, etc by itself.

Comment: While experimenting with Android Studio 2.2 - I found that I have to import using the gradle version supplied with studio, rather than the default.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `include ':'` instead of `import ':'`in the settings.gradle file?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, when I tried to open an existing gradle project and AS didn't recognize it like a gradle project, the problem was inside `settings.gradle` file. `settings.gradle` was corrupt because, for some reason, the semicolon was missing. The right structure is `include ':app';` where app is the name of the project's module.

Also, if you need, you can put more than one module, like this: `include ':module1', ':module2', ':module3';`

I hope it could help someone.

Answer (score 3):

In my case: **Step 1:**  Project Structure > Settings.gradle (Open it and add--   **include ':app';** .

**Step 2:** Goto Gradle Tab (It normally present in Left or Right of Android Studio) > Then click to **Refresh All Gradle Project**

**Step 3:** Bang....... I hope its work.(Its works for me)

Comment: This worked for me... the settings.gradle file was missing - i created it and followed your instructions and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

All I did was to try importing the project with the "import Gradle, Eclipse ETC" option at the start window of Android Studio, selected my gradle-incompatible project to import, and then it did import by asking me automatically if I wanted to make a gradle build project and voila it did import correctly this time with no errors.

The process is pretty straightforward, nothing to fiddle around with nasty settings, just follow the IDE auto-fixes and it will work.

At last that worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Just check if you are importing the right folder which contains .gradle and .idea folder

Answer (score -1):

1. click on File
2. Click on Import Projects
3. Click on Users then AndroidStudioProjects
4. Choose your Project then Click OK

   *NOTE: If you are moving from eclipse to Android Studio then you have do exactly same thing but choose the eclipse projects.*