# import project from github into android studio says it's not gradle based project

Tags: android, github, android-studio

As the title says, I've imported a project I've been working on from github into android studio. It has build.gradle files, and settings.gradle. Why does it say it's not a gradle based file?

Am I missing something that I needed to do when I pulled it from github? I just followed the android studio import from github option. What else do I have to do...?

When I try to do a gradle sync, it tells me the project isn't gradle based.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606504/cant-migrate-project-to-gradle-in-android-studio

Comment: that was pretty much it. I just needed to import the project as a gradle project