# Migrate project to gradle error on Android Studio

Tags: android

I just downloaded a project from GitHub to learn from those that know better; [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbP1A.png). After extracting the project and importing it to my android studio, it gave me "migrate project to gradle" error.

I have imported using gradle but to no avail.
This is the screenshot of my studio:
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opcd8.png)

Comment: Take a look at this: [Migrating to Gradle](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/intellij_to_gradle)

Answer (score 1):

As per [@scott-barta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2985303/scott-barta) ([Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21609757/4180965))

> The project thinks it's still a non-Gradle based project; it's not the presence of the build.gradle file that makes it Gradle-based, but
>   it's how the project was set up in the first place.

**You'll need to re-import your project to finish the conversion to Gradle.**

1. First, though, it looks like you don't have a settings.gradle file; it looks like you need one. Since you've set up your project as a single-module project, then you can put the file in your project's root directory, next to build.gradle. It should contain this:

   import ':'
2. In the future if you add more modules to your project you may want
   to convert it to a multi-module directory structure, but you don't
   need to worry about that now. In any event, now you need to do the
   re-import in Android Studio:
3. Close your project, Back up your project, Delete the .idea folder in
   the root directory of the project and Delete all the .iml files in your
   project. Import your project in Android Studio, and in the dialog
   that prompts you for a file, choose the build.gradle file. After
   this you should be good to go.

---

If that does not help, this will guide you through the process: [Migrate existing project to Gradle.](https://coderwall.com/p/npki6q/migrate-existing-android-project-to-gradle)