# How to import a project correctly?

Tags: android-studio, github, import

I do not know how to import a project from GitHub correctly.

https://github.com/rolandsarosy/The-Guardian-API

When I import the project I get this:

```
        Migrate Project to Gradle?
        This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the 
        Gradle build system.
```

And there are no Gradle files.
P.S. I have just started , therefore I am kind of a newbie. Btw, an explanation would 
 not be bad)
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly import github projects into Android Studio. File -> New -> Project from Version Control -> GitHub. Then enter your github username and password.Select the repository and hit clone.

The github repo will be created as a new project in android studio.

To fix the error go to Gradle Scripts->build.gradle(Module:app) and the add the dependecies:

```
dependencies {      
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])  
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'  
}
```

You can also try this.

click the "Clone or download" button of the project you want to import --> download the ZIP file and unzip it. In Android Studio Go to File -> New Project -> Import Project and select the newly unzipped folder -> press OK. It will build the Gradle automatically

Comment: The project thinks it's still a non-Gradle based project; but it's how the project was set up in the first place. You'll need to re-import your project to finish the conversion to Gradle.

Comment: if it still doesnt work you can check out this link to help you out https://stackoverflow.com/a/21609757/1525681

Comment: Hey I found the problem. But your answer is pretty good. I hope someone will find it useful